# How to express cell id using string letter and current row number in an Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate the sum on a column and then subtract sum on another column **BUT** using only the values from a given row to the current row (the one in which formula resides).

So, in an "informal custom language", I would need something like this:

Suppose I am in **C5**: `=(sum(A1:"A"+ROW())-sum(B1:"B"+ROW()))`

How can I write a correct expression in Excel for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try using `INDIRECT`, which accepts a string reference to a range and returns the range itself:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW()))-SUM(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()))
```

Here, we start with a 'stub' of `"A1:A"`. We then get the current row with `ROW()` (so 5 in this example) and concatenate it with our stub, giving us `INDIRECT("A1:A5")`. Since `INDIRECT` will return the range referenced by its argument (`"A1:A5"` here), we can wrap it with the `SUM` formula to get the result (which is identical to `SUM(A1:A5)`). We then do the same thing for column `B`.

Comment: Using INDEX would arguably be less volatile, i.e. `=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()))-SUM(B1:INDEX(B:B,ROW()))`

Comment: @barryhoudini Avoid hard-coded references and keep it dynamic, can't argue with that at all (I'll definitely vote for that if you post it).

Answer (score 7):

I think you may be looking at it backwards. You need to anchor the first cell reference in the call to `SUM` to the first row, but let the second cell reference change with the row.  Try this in cell **C1**:

```
=SUM(A$1:A1) - SUM(B$1:B1)
```

Now when you copy that down the column, it becomes:

> **C2:** =SUM(A$1:A2) - SUM(B$1:B2)
>   **C3:** =SUM(A$1:A3) - SUM(B$1:B3)
>   **C4:** =SUM(A$1:A4) - SUM(B$1:B4)
>   **C5:** =SUM(A$1:A5) - SUM(B$1:B5)

Comment: +1 - if the intent isn't to have arbitrarily spaced 'subtotal' cells throughout the data and instead perform the calculation on every row, I vote this way :)

Comment: Yes, this is a great answer. But since I have asked specifically for a concatenation way I belive the correct answer is the first one. +1 too. If there isn't a question for this answer, it should be created! :)

Comment: Using INDIRECT is generally a bad idea as it can slow excel calculation significantly: Bill's answer is the correct answer to what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

```
C5:= (SUM))-(SUM))
```

Try this:

```
C5:= (SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A" & ROW()))-(SUM(INDIRECT("B1:B" & ROW()))
```